# XAMLX Workflow with c# expressions

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm developing a self host workflow in vs2012/.Net 4.5/WF 4.5 and having quite a hard time figuring out the following message

> Expression Activity type 'CSharpValue`1' requires compilation in order to run. Please ensure that the workflow has been compiled.

This error happens when i call a activity generated by a service reference (When you add a WCF service reference, each action on the endpoint become a activity).

Looking around in MSDN i've came across these articles:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358749.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29110be7-f4e3-407e-8dbe-78102eb21115#CodeWorkflows

They said that

> When a workflow service is hosted in IIS or WAS then no additional steps are required, but if the XAML workflow service is self-hosted, then the C# expressions must be compiled

So, i finally get to my question: **What should I do so i can hit F5 and debug my workflow, having it run on IIS? and stop this god damn exception...**

I've tried to go to the project config and set to use local IIS as follow: [image: iis config]

but since i still get the error i assume it's not working...

Comment: Leonardo have you had any further luck with this problem? I seem to be falling into the same trap as you. :(

Comment: @FryHard actually no... i ended up answering my own question... it's a simple configuration... disapointing? yes, but it's ok...

Comment: I even get this error after Publishing a precompiled workflow web site to IIS. Seems that the C# support is less than half-baked...

Comment: I have now finally figured out why I get this error: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779794/assign-activity-csharpvalue-expression-with-newline-cannot-exceed-256-characters

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Despite what the article said about running on IIS/WAS I only managed to run the workflow when I implemented the fabric sugested... this is not an answer for the question... its more like a workaround...

Comment: Could you be more precise in describing what you did to make it work?

Comment: @TorbenRahbekKoch i did as the article said: copy/pasted the provided code in a new class then i just set the class as factory in the workflow settings (web.config)...

Comment: Sorry. Cannot find anything about using the class as factory in any of the two mentioned articles. Seems that my problem was unrelated anyway. I forgot to Bind some run-time elements which were using `CSharpReference`.

Comment: Seems I still could use some details about your solution. I now have the problem in a Decision Node with a very simply comparison expression.

Comment: This answer is far too vague

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but after a day of piecing together various bits of information, I thought I'd share just in case someone else runs into this.

From the C# expressions MSDN documentation:

C# expressions are supported in XAMLX workflow services. **When a workflow service is hosted in IIS or WAS then no additional steps are required**, but if the XAML workflow service is self-hosted, then the C# expressions must be compiled.

This is true until you add a custom WorkflowHostFactory.  In that case, if you override the wrong method, your C# will NOT be compiled.  The following code does NOT compile C# expressions and you will get the dreaded:

> Expression Activity type 'CSharpValue`1' requires compilation in order to run. Please ensure that the workflow has been compiled.

Or, if you're not looking at tracing messages, the even more helpful:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The operation could not be performed because WorkflowInstance '5cfc33d1-b546-4ba8-a8ec-86d3cb16a68b' was aborted.

```
   public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return base.CreateServiceHost(constructorString, baseAddresses);
    }
```

You can fix this by overriding the other factory method and then compiling your activity using the code provided via MSDN [C# Expressions in Workflow Foundation 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591618%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 protected override WorkflowServiceHost CreateWorkflowServiceHost(WorkflowService service, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        CompileExpressions(service.Body);
        return base.CreateWorkflowServiceHost(service, baseAddresses);
    }
```

Here is the whole WorkflowServiceHostFactory:

```
 public class MyWorkflowServiceHostFactory : WorkflowServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override WorkflowServiceHost CreateWorkflowServiceHost(WorkflowService service, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        CompileExpressions(service.Body);
        return base.CreateWorkflowServiceHost(service, baseAddresses);
    }

    static void CompileExpressions(Activity activity)
    {
        // activityName is the Namespace.Type of the activity that contains the
        // C# expressions.
        string activityName = activity.GetType().ToString();

        // Split activityName into Namespace and Type.Append _CompiledExpressionRoot to the type name
        // to represent the new type that represents the compiled expressions.
        // Take everything after the last . for the type name.
        string activityType = activityName.Split('.').Last() + "_CompiledExpressionRoot";
        // Take everything before the last . for the namespace.
        string activityNamespace = string.Join(".", activityName.Split('.').Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse());

        // Create a TextExpressionCompilerSettings.
        TextExpressionCompilerSettings settings = new TextExpressionCompilerSettings
        {
            Activity = activity,
            Language = "C#",
            ActivityName = activityType,
            ActivityNamespace = activityNamespace,
            RootNamespace = null,
            GenerateAsPartialClass = false,
            AlwaysGenerateSource = true,
            ForImplementation = false
        };

        // Compile the C# expression.
        TextExpressionCompilerResults results =
            new TextExpressionCompiler(settings).Compile();

        // Any compilation errors are contained in the CompilerMessages.
        if (results.HasErrors)
        {
            throw new Exception("Compilation failed.");
        }

        // Create an instance of the new compiled expression type.
        ICompiledExpressionRoot compiledExpressionRoot =
            Activator.CreateInstance(results.ResultType,
                new object[] { activity }) as ICompiledExpressionRoot;

        // Attach it to the activity.
        CompiledExpressionInvoker.SetCompiledExpressionRoot(
            activity, compiledExpressionRoot);
    }       
}
```