# What can cause WF4 to complain about out-of-sequence calls improperly?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation-4.5

I have a (pretty) simple workflow.  The first three actions on the workflow are:

1. GetWorkflowId  (a simple custom step to retrieve the workflow ID)
2. InitializeCorrelation (vanilla)
3. Receive Xyz

There are 9 receives in the workflow in all.  When I run through them all in my unit test (using WorkflowServiceTestHost) it works just fine.

However, when I try to call the first receive entrypoint (Xyz) from a client, I get the following error:

> Operation 'Xyz|{http://tempuri.org/}IService' on service instance with
>   identifier 'ffd6c56d-529f-4f42-ba81-f30c5ea9348d' cannot be performed
>   at this time. Please ensure that the operations are performed in the
>   correct order and that the binding in use provides ordered delivery
>   guarantees.

I have tried all sorts of things to get more information on this but come up empty.  I have a SQL Server persistence database and have checked it for the workflow instance but the InstancesTable there is always empty.

I am beginning to wonder if I have hit a bug in WF4.

Answer (score 0):

The error displayed was bogus and misleading.   The real error was

> System.NotSupportedException: Expression Activity type 'CSharpValue`1'
>   requires compilation in order to run.  Please ensure that the workflow
>   has been compiled.

Which I found when I enabled WF tracing (see [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518966(v=vs.110).aspx)).  Looking at the related questions 
[XAMLX Workflow with c# expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753276/xamlx-workflow-with-c-sharp-expressions)
and
[Activity throws exception when C# expression uses reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915005/activity-throws-exception-when-c-sharp-expression-uses-reference-types)
I realized that since I had overridden `WorkflowServiceHostFactory` that I now had to explicitly compile the C# expressions.  Doing so in the override fixed the problem.

The results look something like this:

```
 public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
 {
     var result = new WorkflowServiceHostFactory().CreateServiceHost(constructorString, baseAddresses) as WorkflowServiceHost;
     WorkflowUtilities.CompileExpressions(result.Activity);
     return result;
 }
```

Where `WorkflowUtilities` is the class in which I put the pasted-from-elsewhere code for doing the expression compilations.